# What is the 'minimum' needed to make an Applicative a Monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, applicative, category-theory

The `Monad` typeclass can be defined in terms of `return` and `(>>=)`. However, if we already have a `Functor` instance for some type constructor `f`, then this definition is sort of 'more than we need' in that `(>>=)` and `return` could be used to implement `fmap` so we're not making use of the `Functor` instance we assumed.

In contrast, defining `return` and `join` seems like a more 'minimal'/less redundant way to make `f` a `Monad`. This way, the `Functor` constraint is essential because `fmap` cannot be written in terms of these operations. (Note `join` is not necessarily the only minimal way to go from `Functor` to `Monad`: I think `(>=>)` works as well.)

Similarly, `Applicative` can be defined in terms of `pure` and `(<*>)`, but this definition again does not take advantage of the `Functor` constraint since these operations are enough to define `fmap`.

However, `Applicative f` can also be defined using `unit :: f ()` and `(>*<) :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)`. These operations are not enough to define `fmap` so I would say in some sense this is a more minimal way to go from `Functor` to `Applicative`.

Is there a characterization of `Monad` as `fmap`, `unit`, `(>*<)`, and some other operator which is minimal in that none of these functions can be derived from the others?

- `(>>=)` does not work, since it can implement `a >*< b = a >>= (\ x -> b >>= \ y -> pure (x, y))` where `pure x = fmap (const x) unit`.
- Nor does `join` since `m >>= k = join (fmap k m)` so `(>*<)` can be implemented as above.
- I suspect `(>=>)` fails similarly.

Comment: The functor with `unit` and `>*<` is called _lax monoidal_. So your question is what is the minimal extension that would turn a lax monoidal functor into a monad. I don't know the answer, but there's one thing to keep in mind: In Haskell, lax monoidal is equivalent to applicative because Hask is closed monoidal. This wouldn't work in an arbitrary category.

Answer (score 7):

I have something, I think.  It's far from elegant, but maybe it's enough to get you unstuck, at least. I started with `join :: m (m a) -> ???` and asked "what could it produce that would require `(<*>)` to get back to `m a`?", which I found a fruitful line of thought that probably has more spoils.

If you introduce a new type `T` which can only be constructed inside the monad:

```
t :: m T
```

Then you could define a join-like operation which requires such a `T`:

```
joinT :: m (m a) -> m (T -> a)
```

The only way we can produce the `T` we need to get to the sweet, sweet `a` inside is by using `t`, and then we have to combine that with the result of `joinT` somehow.  There are two basic operations that can combine two `m`s into one: `(<*>)` and `joinT` -- `fmap` is no help.  `joinT` is not going to work, because we'll just need yet another `T` to use its result, so `(<*>)` is the only option, meaning that `(<*>)` can't be defined in terms of `joinT`.

You could roll that all up into an existential, if you prefer.

```
joinT :: (forall t. m t -> (m (m a) -> m (t -> a)) -> r) -> r
```